# Trademark positioning in Outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email

I have a client that is nit picking the position of a trademark symbol and doesnt want to use the sup because it is too high.

So i have this

```
  <table>  
    <tr>
      <td class="mobilePadding  mobileFontFix" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="background:#fff;padding:40px 20px 10px 40px;color: #636363;line-height: 22px;font-size: 24px;">
       Some Test Before <span style="font-size: 14px;position: relative;bottom: 4px;">&trade;</span> some Text after
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

But of course Outlook doesn't support position:relative

Any other thoughts on how i can move the trademark up slightly in a way that outlook will render it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions I would have would be:

1. Use the `<sup>` tag, but add a `<span>` around the outside, with the `<span>` containing `style="font-size:Xpx; line-height:Xpx;"` , ensuring that "X" for the line-height and font-size are smaller than the rest of the of your styled text, this will bring it down lower in terms of height.
2. Replace the TM symbol with an image of the symbol, this may give you more flexibility with it's position by using padding or spacers.

Comment: That my friend is the out of the box thinking i was looking for with turning it into an image! ... I did try the span and sup but that wasnt working but the image worked like a charm!

Comment: @Travis Glad I could help! It's worth keeping in mind you can use that for any symbol that may not render correctly on certain platforms (Such as &#9658; which won't render in Android 2.3) One word of warning is that sometimes with those small images, Outlook 2013 can make the text around them push downwards making the image seem higher up. (Sometimes it happens to me sometimes it doesn't) The other thing is that Outlook 2013 also can give images a greater line-height if they're below a certain size, so I always style the containing <td? with 1px line-height and 1px font-size.

Comment: Gotcha yeah i will have to play with that. It looked perfect in Outlook 2010 :)